# Legal way to register custom variable finder in RobotFramework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, robotframework

Does RobotFramework have legal way to register my own variable finder? For example, i want to register finder that resolves variables thats name starts with `#`. With `robotframework==3.1` I was able to achieve this with code like this:

```py
import robot
from robot.variables.finders import VariableFinder


class MyVariableResolver:
    identifiers = '$'

    def find(self, name):
        if name[2] == '#':
            return f'My resolution for {name}'
        else:
            raise KeyError(name)
            

VariableFinder._finders = property(
    lambda self: (MyVariableResolver(),) + self.__dict__['_finders'],
    lambda self, value: self.__dict__.setdefault('_finders', value)
)


class MyLibrary:
    pass
```

With `robotframework==4.0` my solution was broken and I had to change `MyVariableResolver` to:

```py
from robot.variables.finders import NOT_FOUND
# other imports

class MyVariableResolver:
    identifiers = '$'

    def find(self, name):
        if name[2] == '#':
            return f'My resolution for {name}'
        else:
            return NOT_FOUND
```

But this code still looks very ugly (especially `VariableFinder._finders = property(...`). Is there a "right" way to do what I want?